# Can I remove and replace everything after a specific DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Is there an way to delete everything after a particular div with javascript/jquery and replace with new code?

The DIV's are generated dynamically and I want to be able to delete everything after
the last div which looks something like:

```
            <div class="galImage"> **div content** </div>
            /**delete everything after this point and replace with code below**/
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried `$('.galImage').nextAll().remove();` which I found else where on stackoverflow but it doesn't seem to have any effect - is `nextAll()` even a legitimate function?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Comment: FYI: You should think of these as nodes that encompass the entire element including the opening, closing, and all descendants. So if you remove a nested node, it doesn't affect the "closing tags" of its ancestors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear because you've posted what appears to be a fragment of markup.

From what I can tell, you want to remove a `textNode`. Selectors and most jQuery traversal methods can't find text nodes, but you can select it using the native API.

```
var galimg = $('.galImage')[0];  // <-- get the DOM element

    // traverse to its parent, and remove the node that is after the galImage
galimg.parentNode.removeChild( galimg.nextSibling );
```

---

If there are additional nodes to remove, then you can use a loop:

```
var galimg = $('.galImage')[0];
var node;

while( node = galimg.nextSibling ) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
}
```

---

Considering that you're using jQuery, if there are indeed actual elements (not just text nodes) to remove, you should use `.remove()`, otherwise jQuery's cache won't be updated, which could cause a memory leak.

```
var galimg = $('.galImage')[0];
var node;

while( node = galimg.nextSibling ) {
    $(node).remove();
}
```

---

Or if you want a full jQuery solution, you could do this:

```
var galimg = $('.galImage');
var nodes = galimg.parent().contents(); // <-- .contents() includes text nodes
var idx = nodes.index( galimg );   // <-- get the index of galImage

nodes.slice( idx + 1 ).remove();  // <-- take a slice of the nodes, starting at
                                  //       the index after the galImage
```

Comment: Many thanks! Sorry for the fragment - i just want to focus on the question. Your right, its a text node of base64 i want to remove, I just didn't know that was what it was called. Both this and the nextAll solution both work great. But for my App, while your node loop removal does seem to have some interesting results you can probably see on this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/W45pc.jpg the problem is a little more complex and Im not sure this is the way to go. cheers!

Comment: @danssker: You mean the loop is *causing* that scrambled text? If so, that's strange. All it does is simply remove the next sibling of the target as long as there is one. This will remove any type of node it encounters, which is handy if you need to remove text nodes, since `nextAll` won't be able to help.

Comment: No not all, sorry youre code was cool and did exactly what I asked for. I meant that you can see on the screenshot the problem I'm trying to fix. I had partial success with your node loop and also with:    
$( '.galImage *' ).remove(); $( '<p>replacement text here</p>' ).insertAfter( '#galImage' );
But unfortunately I couldn't get it to stick. The base64 code imported along with my galImage just wrecks everything..

Comment: @danssker: Any chance you have a public link to the page that's giving you trouble?

Comment: @danssker: You can go ahead and delete the comment. I've got the link. The gallery page is loading slowly, but I'll see what I can figure out sometime today.

Comment: Its all good now - but many thanks for offering your help. Turned out to be an issue with our local server set up. Strange that it didn't work before i guess it might be a mix of tweeks to code and storing the app on external server. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`nextAll` requires a selector. E.g.:

```
$('#afterme').nextAll('*').remove();
```

See a fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/philwinkle/c5bGP/

Comment: In addition: if you wanted to just remove all of the following `div` tags, you need to use `.nextAll('div')`. The above code removes everything that follows the div, period.

Comment: according to `jquery` documentation `selector` is optional

Comment: `nextAll` does not require a selector. Your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/c5bGP/1/

Comment: Nice one, that works perfectly and a good trick to know, but while it might not need a selector, it doesn't seem to want to remove a basic text string. The code I'm trying to remove has no recogonisable tags, hence the need for a blanket delete of everything after my last <div>

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = $('.myDiv').index(this);

$('div:gt(index)').remove();
```

That look ok?

Comment: It looks good. Will it work on removing a basic text string that is outside of any containers?

Comment: You're going to need to look into text nodes for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using remove, will remove the element from the body so it will not be shown, though it still exists in the DOM.

Since it is all dynamic anyway, you could use load in one of 2 ways: load the content of each div, or load all the html for the divs

`$('#container').load('path/to/data');`

When you use load on a div, it will replace the data that is already there.

Comment: I would love to use remove, but the element is a just text string with nothing to target...

Comment: If there is nothing to target, then you should do 1 of 2 things...1, use the '*' selector and delete everything as mentioned in another post, or 2, add a target.  When using load or ajax you can load html into a div, including other divs. So instead of loading a standard string `My text`, you could load `<div class="dyntext">My text</div>`.  With this, you could easily remove the divs using the class selector `$('.dyntext').remove()`

Comment: Nice - but the problem is its an unwanted base64 string that is being injected into my DOM (but strangely only on Apple, not on windows) see from the screenshot on other answer, it seems to create its own (very strange looking) div's....

Comment: in that picture you posted, what all is unwanted?  all the stuff with base64? which looks like the element with id "page1" and its siblings. is this correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct. In Safari on windows it all works fine, but on apple mac, its like it loads the picture requested, but then continues loading in every other picture as base64, killing my app.

Can i pm you a link to the app?

Comment: Sure, I will try to take a look at it today.

Comment: cool- apparently there's no pm on stack so i emailed your website... cheers mate!